# Not sure why i am getting uninitialized constant AddTableDefaults::TableDefault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Created migration using

> rails generate migration add_table_defaults

```
class AddTableDefaults < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def up
        create_table :table_defaults do |t|
          t.string :table_name, null: false, uniq: true
          t.jsonb :default_values
        end

        TableDefault.create(
          table_name: 'test',
          default_values: [{name:test}]
        )

      end

      def down
        drop_table :table_defaults
      end
    end
```

Getting the error saying uninitialized constant AddTableDefaults::TableDefault while doing

> rake db:migrate

This is straight forward not sure where i am doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you need to prepend `::` to the model name, like `::TableDefault`

Comment: @mr_sudaca this will not work

Comment: can you run the rake task with `--trace` and paste the output?

Comment: @Kunal did you try the suggestion..? Your migration thinks you are looking for a class called AddTableDefaults::TableDefault, by un-namespacing it you should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure @mr_sudaca's solution works - however if it definitely doesn't, just define the class inside the migration:

```
class AddTableDefaults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class TableDefault < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def up
    create_table :table_defaults do |t|
      t.string :table_name, null: false, uniq: true
      t.jsonb :default_values
    end
     TableDefault.create(
      table_name: 'test',
      default_values: [
        {name:test}
      ]
    )
  end

  def down
    drop_table :table_defaults
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't name a column on your table `table_name`. `self.table_name` is the attribute used by ActiveRecord models to keep track of the track of which table the model reads/writes from and is thus a really bad choice.

Comment: A better question is why your even defining table defaults as a separate table with a json column. This is like the godfather of all SQL antipatterns. Use `ActiveRecord::Attibutes` or regular database defaults and KISS.

Answer (score -2):

Problem Here was model was not available and i was trying to feed the data into the table